# "Copy to Oracle" Procedure in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two database connections in SQL Developer, one Oracle database and the other SQL Server database. When I right click on a table in the SQL Server database, I can see an option to "Copy to Oracle" which creates the table in my Oracle Database and inserts the data into the table.

My goal is to create a procedure that completes this same task so that I can run the table creation/replacement process once a day through the scheduler. I'm not even sure this is possible, but if SQL Developer is accomplishing it through the GUI, I assume there is a series of statements that can be put into a procedure to do the same thing.

Comment: Have you looked into replication? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I think setting up the replication might be overkill for what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: You could setup an SSIS package and run it on a schedule.

Comment: sqldev does this via a jdbc call to each db. under the covers it's the same sqlcl bridge  command. from plsql, there's a couple choice like a java proc using jdbc or sql server gateway.

Comment: @SeanLange I am very new to SQL in general, and am self-teaching myself pretty much everything as I come across new problems, could you explain what the SSIS package is?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/sql-server-integration-services?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @KrisRice Can you explain alittle bit more what you mean by java proc or sql server? After reading through Sean's suggestion, I have realized that I can't schedule a job because my login is not an admin on the SQL server database. So I'm going to have to try it execute it your way.

Comment: @SeanLange Unfortunately, I can't schedule a job with the permissions I have for the SQL Server database :(

Comment: I can later on a plane at the moment :)

Comment: Well for something like this I would see about either getting permission or have somebody else schedule it.

Comment: @KrisRice Thank you!